# How to get .selected String?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

I'm using JS to search in an XML and get it's elements in order to use it in further processing, I'm using [heapbox](http://www.bartos.me/heapbox) to display the elements and then using `.selected` to get the selected element in order to display it's children.

The problem here is that i want to get the selected element in order to make some name processing before getting children, but i got nothing when storing it in a `var` and got it works when using the full query directly,

for ex,

```
var section = '', text = '' ; 
section = $('menu').find($(".selected").text()).attr('nodeName');
alert($('menu').find($(".selected").text()).attr('nodeName'));
```

in that code `section` equals nothing, `text` equals nothing, it **alerts** `undefined`, while using `$('menu').find($(".selected").text()).attr('nodeName')` directly in processing works very good.

**UPDATE:**

**xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu parent_id="0" >

    <Menu cat="main">

    </Menu> 
    <Soup cat="main">
            <Mushrom0Tomato.Soap  price = "15.95" hasoption = "false"> 
            </Mushrom0Tomato.Soap>
            <Cream.Of.Chicken.Soap  price = "16.95" hasoption = "true"> 

                    <Add.Mushroom  price = "3.95"></Add.Mushroom>
                    <none  price = "0"></none>

            </Cream.Of.Chicken.Soap>
            <Season.Soap  price = "15.95" hasoption = "false">
            </Season.Soap>
    </Soup>
</menu>
```

**JS code:**

```
var cats=[], cati=0, total=0, selectedarray=[], itemoptions=[], optionstring='', section='', si=0, oi=0, items=[];

$("#total").append("Total:  " + total + " EGP");

$('#dummy').load('cafe.xml',function() {
initialize();
})
function initialize(){
ct=$('menu').children().length;
for(cati==0;cati<=ct-1;cati++)
{
cats[cati]=$('menu').children().eq(cati).prop('nodeName');

var realname = cats[cati];
if(realname.indexOf(".") != -1){
    realname = realname.replace(/\./g,' ');
    }

$('.basic-example').append('<option value="option1">'+realname+'</option>');
}
$(".basic-example").heapbox({'onChange':function(){loadmenu()},effect:{type:"fade",speed:"slow"}});

}



// loading the items to the menu
function loadmenu()
{

$("#gallery").empty();
section = $('menu').find($(".selected").text()).attr('nodeName');
alert($("menu .selected").text().toString());
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

`.find` is meant for finding children elements of a selected node

You probably just want

```
$("menu .selected").text();
```

And

```
$("menu .selected").attr("nodeName");
```

---

The `.find` equivalent of this (although probably unnecessary) would be

```
$("menu").find(".selected").text();
```

And

```
$("menu").find(".selected").attr("nodeName");
```

Comment: but when alerting `$("menu .selected").text();` it gives me a null string

Comment: I can't help you unless you actually post the code and data you're working with.